# Error in perlipc documentation?

Tags: perl, ipc

I'm trying to puzzle through something I see in the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) documentation.

> If you're writing to a pipe, you should also trap SIGPIPE.  Otherwise,
>   think of what happens when you start up a pipe to a command that
>   doesn't exist: the open() will in all likelihood succeed (it only
>   reflects the fork()'s success), but then your output will
>   fail--spectacularly.  Perl can't know whether the command worked
>   because your command is actually running in a separate process whose
>   exec() might have failed.  Therefore, while readers of bogus commands
>   return just a quick end of file, writers to bogus command will trigger
>   a signal they'd better be prepared to handle.  Consider:

```
   open(FH, "|bogus")  or die "can't fork: $!";
   print FH "bang\n"   or die "can't write: $!";
   close FH            or die "can't close: $!";
```

> That won't blow up until the close, and it will blow up with a
>   SIGPIPE. To catch it, you could use this:

```
   $SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';
   open(FH, "|bogus")  or die "can't fork: $!";
   print FH "bang\n"   or die "can't write: $!";
   close FH            or die "can't close: status=$?";
```

If I'm reading that correctly, it says that the first version will probably not die until the final close.

However, that's not happening on my OS X box (Perl versions 5.8.9 through 5.15.9). It blows up on the `open` with a "can't fork: No such file or directory" regardless of whether or not I have the $SIG{PIPE} line in there.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think `open` was changed to better report that case and `perlipc` wasn't updated; you can still get the documented behavior, but you need to use the more verbose `open(..., '|-')` mechanism.

Comment: geekosaur: switching to `open my $fh, '|-', ''bogus" or die ` gives the same error.

Comment: Erm.  I meant the *really* long way, where you don't specify a command at all but instead the script itself `fork`s and you run `exec` in the child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a change implemented back during development of 5.6 so that system() could detect when it failed to fork/exec the child

https://github.com/mirrors/perl/commit/d5a9bfb0fc8643b1208bad4f15e3c88ef46b4160

It is also documented in http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perlopentut.pod#Pipe_Opens

which itself points to perlipc, but perlipc does seem to be missing this

Answer (score 0):

Same output on my Perl, `v5.14.2`, Ubuntu 12.04:

```
$ perl
   open(FH, "|bogus")  or die "can't fork: $!";
   print FH "bang\n"   or die "can't write: $!";
   close FH            or die "can't close: $!";
can't fork: No such file or directory at - line 1.
```

And that error is *odd*, since it has nothing to do with forking -- they must have added some lookahead-guessing to see if it could execute `bogus`. (Which would be a *race condition* at best, but one likely to provide significantly better error handling in the common case; and only be as inconvenient as the old behavior when the race is lost.)

Comment: Not necessarily guessing; given that Perl already tries to use an internal `PATH` search and `exec` if no shell metacharacters are involved, it is already detecting "not found" beforehand.

Comment: @geekosaur: but the `bogus` may be in the `PATH` _and executable_ when the `execve()` call eventually comes. Yes, it's only milliseconds away, but [race conditions are rarely this benign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use). :)

Comment: I think that only counts as a race condition if you're writing that code with the specific expectation that it will fail.

Comment: Yeah, it'd depend upon the timing of `chmod a-x /bin/bogus` during the execution of this program to get different behaviors. It'd be tricky to trip.